# Protege Ontology - creating individuals

Tags: ontology, protege, clips

I'm doing for the first time an ontology in Protege, but I have never worked with it. 
I have a manufacturing process, where I have two robots, a machine tool, two storages (S1 and S2), a working table, a computer vision system, a conveyor and 6 types of pieces (A, B, C, D, E, F). I have some goals set (ex: Storage S2 must have a piece of type A in position (row, column) (1,4) with orientation orientation1. I though to create a class for Robot which will have the following properties: hasState (the robot can be free or can have a piece), hasPosition (the robot can be in four predefined positions) and hasPiece.
The question is the following: when I will create the individuals for the two robots, what I will set in the hasPiece properties? I need to create the ontology in Protege and after that, to create a CLIPS program that will resolve the problem(will move the pieces from the storage S1 in storage S2 in the desired positions). Will the individuals be the initial facts? I only saw examples of ontologies for pizza and countries and these didn't have properties that will be modified during CLIPS program running.

Answer (score 0):

> Will the individuals be the initial facts?

I would assume so from your description.

Individuals and properties are created the same way no matter how they will be subsequently modified. I would assume that all you need to change from the pizza example is the name of properties, classes and individuals required.